# UIImage size is larger than what I set it to

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm doing some basic line drawing using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    let path = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    path!.setLineWidth(1.5)
....
    x = (az / 360) * Double(size.width)
    y = halfheight - Double(alt / 90 * halfheight)
    path?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:x, y:y))
    path?.strokePath()
....
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //DEBUGGING - makes quick look work
    let _ = image!.cgImage
    return image!
```

The debugger reports the right size for the image, 1440x960. But when I use QuickLook, the image is 2880 × 1920 pixels. I'm curious if there is an obvious reason for this? Is this something that quicklook is doing, or Preview perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debugger is most likely giving you the size in *points* and Quick Look will be giving you the size in *pixels*.

The problem is that by passing `0` in the `scale` parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, you're using the device's screen scale for the scale of the context. Thus if you're on a device with a 2x display, and input a size of 1440 x 960, you'll get a context with 2880 x 1920 pixels.

If you want to work with pixels instead of points, then simply pass `1` into the `scale` parameter:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1)
```

Or use the equivalent [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623922-uigraphicsbeginimagecontext) call:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
```